How is Teal'c able to use a rope across the stargate event horizon?
According to Stargate franchise canon, a stargate is both a sort of anchor point for a wormhole and a matter teleportation device in that an object (or person) entering the event horizon on the sending side is "de-constructed", transmitted as an energy pattern through the wormhole, and re-constituted by the receiving stargate.
In the SG-1 episode "A Hundred Days", Teal'c fires a harpoon device through the stargate which anchors a rope on the ceiling of the cavern. He next appears suspended near the top of the cavern setting to work digging himself out. We don't see how he crosses the event horizon to end up suspended from the rope at any point on its length. We might imagine the rope somehow ending up continuously spanning the stargates, but that would violate the canon description for how stargates work.
So, how does Teal'c go through the stargate to end up suspended in the cave? Is this a plot hole?

The strongest reference for the "only transmits matter as a discrete and complete unit" is the Atlantis season 1 episode 38 Minutes - we don't see the front of the puddle-jumper materialise at the other end until they are able to free the ship. But the exact physics and behaviour of stargates are driven by plot rather than consistency.

Though that specific episode brings up more questions - like, when they push Sheppard through the event horizon, how does he not materialise fused with the bulkhead?

In the movie that started it all, the very first thing sent through Earth's gate is a tethered robot that sends back images and telemetry through its tether.

As I recall, the way the gates canonically work is by dematerializing anything that touches the event horizon... but there is some magic here, because a) that should instantly kill any living thing, and b) you can stick your arm in and pull it back out. Also, however (and relevant here), in addition to acting like a Star Trek transporter (as noted in the Question), only objects that fully enter the event horizon are sent. Naturally, this is contradicted on occasion; as HorusKol notes, Plot is all powerful.

@SolomonSlow …and at the same time, the same movie shows how everything is deconstructed when going through the gate…

Most episodes of Stargate appear to show some kind of "buffer space" behind each gate, characters walk up to the gate and put a hand 1 or weapon through the horizon and sometimes pull the item back. Hence the transportation effect of the wormhole doesn't appear to engage until either:

The object is completely inside the buffer space.
The gate shuts down - there have been several objects that have been severed 2 when this happens.

One explanation of "The Torment of Tantalus" was that Ernest was simply standing in the buffer space (he could have been pulled back using the pipe) until the moment the gate shut down, at which time he was transported to the other side.
Objects also appear to preserve momentum when they go through the gate: people step through, but ships can move quickly 3 through and come out with the same speed.
In "A Hundred Days" there was a very fast cut immediately following  Teal'c firing the harpoon. If that cut had not been so quick there would have been a problem; when all of the rope had paid out the harpoon would have stopped, since it was attached to Teal'c.
However, given the cut, one possible option is for Teal'c to quickly cross the horizon before the harpoon ran out of rope and started the transfer. Hence the harpoon was able to leave the other gate (with its initial velocity) and embed itself into the ceiling - then Teal'c was able to grab the tail of the rope as he emerged from the gate horizon on the other side. Even if he had fallen back through (slightly) that would not break canon as Jack 1 has put his hand back through gates when he has just arrived to prevent the gate from closing.

1 SG-1: "Shades of Grey" - Jack holds the gate.
2 Atlantis: "Thirty-Eight Minutes" has dialog lines/plot of needing to free themselves before the gate shuts down.
3 Atlantis: "Rising Part 1" - Dart exits the gate at full speed.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You make an interesting point, but this would be a better answer if you could identify specific episodes where the effects you describe occur.

"Objects also appear to preserve momentum". I don't think there is any "appearance"; I seem to recall that this was explicitly stated to happen.

@Matthew The problem is there are over 200 episodes across all the franchises and most involve the gate - so it is difficult to find a specific voice line to backup a specific point, however I am pretty sure there are either voice lines or plot points to back up "Buffer Space", preservation of momentum, what happens when the gate shuts down, etc. However without rewatching everything it's really tough to cite them.

I don't recall specific citations, either. Maybe it's just a style thing; when I recall something as canon (but can't cite), I write "as I recall, X", whereas you write "it appears that X"? At least to me, the former is a stronger statement... and that was all I meant; I am agreeing that, as I recall, these things are explicit canon and not just guesses consistent with what was portrayed.

If it helps, I'm almost positive that the fact that the Stargate preserves momentum was first mentioned in "Upgrades", 4x03, the episode where they got the superspeed bracelets. Sam mentioned it when they were setting their plan for stopping the mothership under construction, and I'm fairly certain that was the first explicit confirmation, as opposed to just showing it. And I think the first confirmation of the matter buffer was in "48 Hours", 5x14, the episode where they had to figure out a way to get Teal'c back when the source Stargate was destroyed mid-transit.

Oh right, and as for what happens when the gate shuts down when something's partway through, that was definitely first shown in  "Enemy Within", 1x02: that was how they killed the Goa'uld-possessed Kawalsky, slicing off the back of his head.

I will admit to being far from an expert on the show, but my impression has been that ropes and cables sent through the gate remain "whole" until the transmission is complete, as per Ernest Littlefield's cable in "The Torment of Tantalus" which remained taut (and could not be pulled back), so there is canonical reasoning for it. Both episodes, as well as "Shades of Grey" are mentioned here as potentially inconsistent handling of how the Stargate works that support this possibility. Their summary is that this is probably a matter of script convenience, but I think it's as likely that there are various safety measures on the gates that result in people largely being transmitted as a whole, even if not all of their limbs crossed the threshold, while inanimate objects, such as rope, only manifest with what remains of them. In this case, Teal'c seems to have fired the harpoon over, whereupon the rope on his side would be taut. Reeling himself in, he contacted the Stargate and was transported, still attached to that part of the rope that was on the other side, and when the gate closed, he was still attached to it.

The rope in the buffer exists simultaneously in both gates' buffers giving the illusion of taut. - Probably Dr. Samantha Carter (fake quote)

Practical considerations: if this weren't the case, then if you poked your head through a stargate, it would decapitate you? Actually, every individual atom coming through the gate would disconnect from your body, as not all of you crosses the gate all at once, and the alleged buffer is finite so the same question applies at the buffer's edges. Secondly, if you throw a ball through a stargate, it keeps moving. Therefore, energy is conserved across a stargate, which means that a rope can be taut if it spans the two locations connected by a gate, as the rope's intermolecular forces are conserved

@Flater: The buffers, although finite, are quite large. The gates can easily transport wraith darts or loaded puddle jumpers, as well as RC rovers, sarcophaguses, and loads of other stuff.

The science of the gates is not quite exact. In S5 E14 "48 Hours", Teal'c is stuck in the Earth gate, until he is saved.
The explanation in this episode, is that the matter is first transferred to the receiving gate, stored in a buffer, and then reconstructed.
Additionally, there are several episodes (minimum 2) in which the gates are kept open by continuously sending some object / energy throughout the gate. Examples: the effects of a black hole, some energy weapon etc.
Another example is keeping the gate open by simply sticking one's hand into it - without the hand appearing on the other end.
So the episode you refer to is like some episodes (some object / energy present at both ends of the gate), and also unlike other episodes (where the sending is done only after the complete object is inside the gate - the hand).

On-screen canon seems to suggest that radio communication through the gate is enough to keep it open, but the environment in the gate room is likely full of EM emanating from all sorts of equipment. The gate would have to distinguish between the low power non-directional transmission of a hand-held radio and the potentially much more powerful RF noise from all the computers, transformers, etc. in the gate room. One might therefore wonder how either (a) a radio transmission can keep it open or (b) a connection to or from SGC could ever shut down.

As we agreed, the science is not very precise there. But your point is indeed good - the room is full of EM radiation, so the gate should not close, or at least close with difficulty.

First, please upvote DavidT's Answer. It's the right idea, but I would like to expand on it.
(The following is entirely recollection, which may be faulty.)
It's been explicitly stated that objects passing through the gate "retain" their velocity. (If you think about it, this is necessary, otherwise nothing coming out the other side would... actually come out. And that would be bad.) It's also been stated that objects are "buffered" until the object has fully crossed the sending event horizon; only then is it transmitted and reconstructed. (Note that it has to be held at the sending gate, because we've seen people wave their hands into the event horizon and pull them out again. If the matter left for the receiving gate instantly, this would require two-way matter travel, which is otherwise stated to be impossible.)
Note that we also know that, when a gate shuts down, anything partly across the event horizon becomes two objects, one of which is presumably transmitted to the receiving gate and reconstructed.
So.. Teal'c shoots a harpoon at the event horizon. As it crosses, it is dematerialized... but the matter is still in the "send buffer".
Before all the rope has run out, Teal'c then steps through himself. (If he waits... probably the rope will start to be pulled back out of the gate and the momentum of the harpoon will be affected, which will cause the plan to not work; therefore, it's reasonable to assume he doesn't wait.) Now that "the whole object" is through, Teal'c and the harpoon are transmitted to the other side. The harpoon exits with enough velocity to strike the far rock.
Here's the fun bit. Teal'c's velocity is... not very high. In order to not fall back through the gate, the length of rope must be very carefully calculated so that it is exactly long enough for the retraction mechanism to be out of the gate when the harpoon is embedded. Too short and the mass of Teal'c's body will stop the harpoon from "sticking". Too long and the retraction mechanism falls back through and dematerializes. In fact, Teal'c's timing might be subject to similar constraints. Since the plan worked, we can assume the Big Brains knew this and got their figures right.  (Is this plausible? Yes. The "sploosh" seems to be very consistent, so it wouldn't be hard to know the exact distance from the far event horizon to where the "sploosh" stopped dematerializing the rock.)
That said, putting the retractor on the harpoon would solve these problems. I don't recall seeing that, but maybe we did see it and I just don't recall, or maybe we can assume that's "what really happened" even if we didn't see it on screen.
